# Oracle SQL: If I use a function both as a field and in order by, is it evaluated again?

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, oracle11g

Suppose you have a `PL/SQL` function that returns some random value that you will use in a `SQL sentence` both as returned data and in the `Order by` clause.

Now you could write the `Order by` clause in three "different" ways:

*By index*

```
Select Foo,
       MyFunction(Foo) orderField
  From FooTable
 Order By 2
```

*By calling "again" the function*

```
Select Foo,
       MyFunction(Foo) orderField
  From FooTable
 Order By MyFunction(Foo)
```

*By using the order field alias*

```
Select Foo,
       MyFunction(Foo) orderField
  From FooTable
 Order By orderField
```

The third way is possible as the `Order By` clause is the last one of the select to be parsed and then Oracle already knows about the alias.

My question is, is there any difference in the processing or performance of these three queries? Particularly, would the second one imply that the `MyFunction` call would be evaluated again?

I tried to find out by searching over the docs, and by running some queries from *Toad* as well as having a look at the `explain plan` but could not find any significant difference until now.

My Oracle version is 11.2.0.3.0, if that matters in any way.

Comment: Could it perhaps depend on if the function is deterministic or not? (Anyway, column alias is my favorite.)

Comment: @jarlh, might well be. I am curious about if anyone knows the answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A good way to check what is going on in such cases is to use sequences (but I have oracle version 12.1). For example:

```
SQL> create sequence func_seq;

Sequence created.

SQL> create or replace function foo return number is
begin
  return func_seq.nextval;
end;
/

Function created.
```

First, make a query that return two rows (without `ORDER BY` clause) and check value of sequence:

```
SQL> select foo from dual connect by level <= 2;

       FOO
----------
         1
         2

SQL> select func_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         2
```

Then a query with `ORDER BY`:

```
SQL> select foo from dual connect by level <= 2 order by foo;

       FOO
----------
         3
         4

SQL> select func_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         4
```

In both cases function was executed 2 times.
But if your function takes arguments, you have to pay attention to their values:

```
SQL> create or replace function foo(p number) return number is
begin
  return func_seq.nextval;
end;
/  

Function created.
```

Make query with different arguments:

```
SQL> select foo(1) from dual connect by level <= 2 order by foo(2);

    FOO(1)
----------
         6
         8

SQL> select func_seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         8
```

As we can see, function was executed 4 times.

Comment: @Dmitry can you check order by foo(1)*2? I cannot bring function running in sql fiddle

Comment: @PavelGatnar In the case with  `order by foo(1)*2` function is executed 4 times (as you have written in your answer).

Answer (score 2):

The function is evaluated only once in your case, the expression in `ORDER BY` clause serves only as a reference to a column in the `SELECT` clause.
When the expression doesn't match, the function will be evaluated twice, e.g.

```
Select Foo,
       MyFunction(Foo) orderField
From FooTable
Order By MyFunction(Foo)*2
```

I would expect Oracle caches the results of deterministic functions (this must be explicitely stated in the function definition), so in such cases the cached result is reused.